# HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for BeginForm for single form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This has been killing me, but I have tried all of the common solutions, none work.

My razor page is throwing this exception after deployment:

> HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for BeginForm

Here is what I've got:

Edit.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadTenantFile", "TenantSubscriptions", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "noprint" }))
            {
                <h4>Upload New File</h4><br />
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                ...
            }
```

web.config in /Views/:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="BetterCompliance.CompliancePortal.Web.Views.CompliancePortalWebViewPageBase">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="BetterCompliance.CompliancePortal.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

In root web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

It might be worth mentioning that a few lines up, the same method without overloads works without an issue:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have found the answer!

Always check your existing using statements at the top of your razor page. One of the VS extensions that I was running added in a FormMethod= using statement, which messed up in my case.

I should also mention that I found 2 other causes on the road:

- The Controller calling the views used the wrong namespace (namespace did not end in .Controller) and
- The ViewBag was used in one of the Views, but no values were defined in the controller